# how to show html page before it was fully downloaded

Tags: python, http

I am sending some data after html content (it has a little delay) in the same response during keep-alive session and want browser to show html before the whole response is downloaded.

For example, I have text `'hello, '` and a function that computes `'world'` with delay (let it be 1 sec). So I want browser to show `'hello, '` immediately and `'world'` with its delay. Is it possible within one request (so, without ajax)

Here is example python code of what I do (highlighted: https://pastebin.com/muUJyR36):

```
import socket
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

def give_me_a_world():
    sleep(1)
    return b'world'

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    response = b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'\
               b'Content-Length: 12\r\n'\
               b'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'\
               b'\r\n'\
               b'hello, '

    conn.send(response) # send first part
    conn.send(give_me_a_world()) # make a delay and send other part

conn.close()
```

Comment: Describe what you've tried.  It's also ambiguous "how" you're sending some data.

Comment: `keep-alive` has nothing to do with this problem, it is based on TCP level, not HTTP.

Comment: Try websockets?

Comment: @cricket_007, As I understood, it opens new request. And browser itself will not initiate websocket, so in this case it is not a solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Socket Flush](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407835/python-socket-flush)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, read [How the web works: HTTP and CGI explained](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html) to understand why and where your current code violates HTTP and thus doesn't and shouldn't work.

Now, as per [Is Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding is mandatory in a response when it has body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832648/is-content-length-or-transfer-encoding-is-mandatory-in-a-response-when-it-has-bo) , after fixing the violation, you should

- omit the `Content-Length` header and close the socket after sending all the data, OR
- calculate the length of the entire data to send beforehand and specify it in the `Content-Length` header

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and omit `Content-Length`.

It works fine on text browsers like **curl** and **Links WWW Browser**. But, modern graphical browsers don't really start rendering until it reaches some sort of buffer boundaries.

```python
import socket
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

def give_me_a_world():
    sleep(1)
    return b'5\r\n'\
           b'world\r\n'\
           b'0\r\n'\
           b'\r\n'

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    response = b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'\
               b'Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n'\
               b'Connection: keep-alive\r\n'\
               b'\r\n'\
               b'7\r\n'\
               b'hello, \r\n'

    conn.send(response) # send first part
    conn.send(give_me_a_world()) # make a delay and send other part

conn.close()
```